# Creating Android XML shape with rectangle and triangle as in figure for Background

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-drawable, shapes

I want to create a drawable android XML Background as shown in the Figure could anybody please tell me how to do this. Thank You!! The Picture of Background is enclosed below[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily achieve this using Vector Drawables. Just create a file `background.xml` and paste the following code:

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="472"
    android:viewportWidth="302" android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#ff008d"
        android:pathData="M0,122.9c0,108.3 0.2,123 1.5,123.5 0.8,0.3 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.5 0,-0.6 0.9,-0.8 2.1,-0.4 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.1,-1 1.5,-0.5 1.6,0.5 2,0.4 1.5,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.3,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.5 0,-0.7 0.7,-1 1.5,-0.6 0.8,0.3 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.5 0,-0.6 0.9,-0.8 2.1,-0.4 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.2,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.4 0,-0.6 0.7,-0.8 1.5,-0.5 0.8,0.4 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.6 0,-0.7 0.8,-0.9 2.1,-0.5 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.1,-1 1.5,-0.5 1.6,0.5 2,0.4 1.5,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.3,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.5 0,-0.7 0.7,-1 1.5,-0.6 0.8,0.3 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.5 0,-0.6 0.9,-0.8 2.1,-0.4 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.1,-1 1.5,-0.5 1.6,0.5 2,0.4 1.5,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.3,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.5 0,-0.7 0.7,-1 1.5,-0.6 0.8,0.3 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.5 0,-0.6 0.9,-0.8 2.1,-0.4 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.1,-1 1.5,-0.5 1.6,0.5 2,0.4 1.5,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.3,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.5 0,-0.7 0.7,-1 1.5,-0.6 0.8,0.3 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.5 0,-0.6 0.9,-0.8 2.1,-0.4 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.2,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.4 0,-0.6 0.7,-0.8 1.5,-0.5 0.8,0.4 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.6 0,-0.7 0.8,-0.9 2.1,-0.5 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.1,-1 1.5,-0.5 1.6,0.5 2,0.4 1.5,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.3,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.5 0,-0.7 0.7,-1 1.5,-0.6 0.8,0.3 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.5 0,-0.6 0.9,-0.8 2.1,-0.4 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.1,-1 1.5,-0.5 1.6,0.5 2,0.4 1.5,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.3,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.5 0,-0.7 0.7,-1 1.5,-0.6 0.8,0.3 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.5 0,-0.6 0.9,-0.8 2.1,-0.4 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.2,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.4 0,-0.6 0.7,-0.8 1.5,-0.5 0.8,0.4 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.6 0,-0.7 0.7,-1 1.5,-0.6 0.8,0.3 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.5 0,-0.6 0.9,-0.8 2.1,-0.4 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.2,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.4 0,-0.6 0.7,-0.8 1.5,-0.5 0.8,0.4 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.6 0,-0.7 0.8,-0.9 2.1,-0.5 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.1,-1 1.5,-0.5 1.6,0.5 2,0.4 1.5,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.3,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.5 0,-0.7 0.7,-1 1.5,-0.6 0.8,0.3 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.5 0,-0.6 0.9,-0.8 2.1,-0.4 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.1,-1 1.5,-0.5 1.6,0.5 2,0.4 1.5,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.3,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.5 0,-0.7 0.7,-1 1.5,-0.6 0.8,0.3 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.5 0,-0.6 0.9,-0.8 2.1,-0.4 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.2,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.4 0,-0.6 0.7,-0.8 1.5,-0.5 0.8,0.4 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.6 0,-0.7 0.8,-0.9 2.1,-0.5 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.1,-1 1.5,-0.5 1.6,0.5 2,0.4 1.5,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.3,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.5 0,-0.7 0.7,-1 1.5,-0.6 0.8,0.3 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.5 0,-0.6 0.9,-0.8 2.1,-0.4 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.1,-1 1.5,-0.5 1.6,0.5 2,0.4 1.5,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.3,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.5 0,-0.7 0.7,-1 1.5,-0.6 0.8,0.3 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.5 0,-0.6 0.9,-0.8 2.1,-0.4 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.2,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.4 0,-0.6 0.7,-0.8 1.5,-0.5 0.8,0.4 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.6 0,-0.7 0.7,-1 1.5,-0.6 0.8,0.3 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.5 0,-0.6 0.9,-0.8 2.1,-0.4 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.2,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.4 0,-0.6 0.7,-0.8 1.5,-0.5 0.8,0.4 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.6 0,-0.7 0.8,-0.9 2.1,-0.5 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.1,-1 1.5,-0.5 1.6,0.5 2,0.4 1.5,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.3,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.5 0,-0.7 0.7,-1 1.5,-0.6 0.8,0.3 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.5 0,-0.6 0.9,-0.8 2.1,-0.4 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.1,-1 1.5,-0.5 1.6,0.5 2,0.4 1.5,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.3,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.5 0,-0.7 0.7,-1 1.5,-0.6 0.8,0.3 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.5 0,-0.6 0.9,-0.8 2.1,-0.4 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.2,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.4 0,-0.6 0.7,-0.8 1.5,-0.5 0.8,0.4 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.6 0,-0.7 0.8,-0.9 2.1,-0.5 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.1,-1 1.5,-0.5 1.6,0.5 2,0.4 1.5,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.3,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.5 0,-0.7 0.7,-1 1.5,-0.6 0.8,0.3 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.5 0,-0.6 0.9,-0.8 2.1,-0.4 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.1,-1 1.5,-0.5 1.6,0.5 2,0.4 1.5,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.3,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.5 0,-0.7 0.7,-1 1.5,-0.6 0.8,0.3 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.5 0,-0.6 0.9,-0.8 2.1,-0.4 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.2,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.4 0,-0.6 0.7,-0.8 1.5,-0.5 0.8,0.4 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.6 0,-0.7 0.7,-1 1.5,-0.6 0.8,0.3 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.5 0,-0.6 0.9,-0.8 2.1,-0.4 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.2,-1 1.4,-0.5 1.2,0.4 2.1,0.2 2.1,-0.4 0,-0.6 0.7,-0.8 1.5,-0.5 0.8,0.4 1.5,0.1 1.5,-0.6 0,-0.7 0.8,-0.9 2.1,-0.5 1.6,0.5 1.9,0.4 1.4,-0.5 -0.5,-0.9 -0.1,-1 1.5,-0.5 1.5,0.5 2,0.4 1.6,-0.4 -0.4,-0.6 -0.2,-1.1 0.3,-1.1 0.8,-0 1.1,-23.5 1.1,-77l0,-77 -151,-0 -151,-0 0,122.9z" android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
</vector>
```

You can change the color by changing the color code of `fillColor`.

Note: You can do the same with any PNG image. Convert the `png` image to `svg` [HERE](https://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-svg). Then in Android Studio go to **File>New>Vector Asset>Local File(SVG,PSD)>Finish**